# How to extract a single element of list-value of function using dplyr/magrittr - R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, magrittr

I'm writing code using `dplyr` and pipes and using `NbClust` function, which returns a list of objects named `All.index`, `All.CriticalValues`, `Best.nc`, `Best.partition`.

So I can assign my expression to some variable and then refer to `Best.nc` element as a `variable$Best.nc`. But how can I extract `Best.nc` element using pipes?

I have tried `purrr::map('[[', 'Best.nc')` but it didn't work.

Comment: You need [to provide a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Best guess without having any of your code or data is `variable %>% pluck("Best.nc")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use the base R `[[` as a function without `map`:

```
lst <- list(a = 1, b = 2)

lst %>% `[[`('a')
# [1] 1

variable %>% `[[`('Best.nc')
```

---

Or with `purrr`, you can use the `pluck` function and simply provide the element index or name:

```
library(purrr)

lst %>% pluck('a')
# [1] 1
lst %>% pluck(1)
# [1] 1
```

For your case:

```
variable %>% pluck('Best.nc')
```

---

The advantage of `pluck` to `[[` extractor is that you can index deeply for a nested list, for instance:

```
lst <- list(a = list(x = list(), y = 'm', z = 1:3), b = 2)
```

To access the `z` element nested in `a`:

```
lst %>% pluck('a', 'z')
# [1] 1 2 3
```